# Tool to diff CSV files at the field level and output results to CSV maintaining the colors

Tags: bash, shell, csv

I am trying to compare 2 csv files at field level difference with color coding the differences. I tried this command

```
git diff --color-words="[^[:space:],]+" x.csv y.csv
```

But there are 2 problems.

1. It puts the cell data that is different besides each other. I don't want that. I just need it to highlighted when there is a difference copy the rows from both csv files to a new csv file.
2. I need the output in csv file along with color coding.

Comment: A CSV file is a plain text file - it's impossible to add "color coding" to it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This website is not a replacement for a search engine. I get these in the first results page: https://pypi.org/project/csvdiff/ and https://github.com/agardiner/csv-diff and http://csvdiff.sourceforge.net/ and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350631/diff-two-large-csv-files-each-90gb-and-output-to-another-csv

Comment: If there is a diff how do I get the diff to a new csv file.  I have tried the command : git diff --color-words="[^[:space:],]+" x.csv y.csv > z.csv     but the z.csv has some weird encoding.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind seeing diff result in a web-app instead of on the command-line then I recommend giving [WRGL](https://www.wrgl.co) a try. It is a full-fledged version control system designed specifically for CSV.

Full disclouse: I am the founder. :)